# Passing an Event from a child component to another child component Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, eventemitter

I have two child components in my app component: `patient-fields` and `patient-analyser`.

The `patient-fields` contains forms and submit button while the `patient-analyser` need the data from the `patient-field` before it performs a POST request to get the patient's data analysed.

My current solution is having EventEmitter from the `patient-fields` that trigger another eventEmmiter object in `App`. Then, I'll pass the app's event emitter to be subscribed by the `patient-analyser` as shown below:

**patient-fields.component.ts (child1):**

```js
 @Output() toggleSubmit: EventEmitter<FormData> = new EventEmitter();

  onSubmit() {
    this.toggleSubmit.emit(this.patientFieldForm.value);
  }
```

**patient-analyser.component.ts (child2):**

```js
  @Input() pf: EventEmitter<any>;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pf.subscribe((data) => {
      // Performing a POST request to analyse the patient data
    });
```

**app.component.ts (parent):**

```js
  @Output() pf: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  onSubmit(patientFields: FormData) {
    this.pf.emit(patientFields);
  }
```

**app.component.html:**

```html
<app-patient-analyser
    [pf] = pf
  ></app-patient-analyser>

<app-patient-fields
    (toggleSubmit)="onSubmit($event)"
  ></app-patient-fields>
```

Is there a better solution for this?

Thanks before.

Comment: If the components are unrelated (In this case, the 2 child components patient-fields and patient-analyser doesn't have a direct connection even though they have the same parent), use a shared service for communication

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should aim for reducing any dependency between components template codes. It will allow you to maximize reusability between your components.

With your current solution, you are forced to tightly couple your components template codes, which means if ever you modify or refactor one of them you are going to run into maintainability issues.

The better way to go is to use an inter-components communication service. The concept is very well explained [here in the Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service).

Here, you should create a service that you inject in all components, where you host the event emitter, and thus you can subscribe/emit without coupling your template codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the behavior subject observable for this,create one behavior subject in a service class and then emit data from patient-fields component and then subscribe this observable inside patient-analyser so that you will have the desired data you wanted.

This approach better than Input/Output property way because each input/output property changes triggers the change detection which is quite expensive operation in angular framework.